# Using P0_item value as a title of modal page Apex 23.1

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have a P0 page item called : `P0_TITLE`

And it get value based on a **application process** which its sequence is first . the value of page item changed based on `APP_LANGUAGE`.

The `APP_LANGUAGE` changes correctly and I'm sure about that.

When I put `&P0_TITLE.` as a title of modal page and I'm on my default language which in ENGLISH , first time when I open up modal page , the title is empty !

and then I changed the language , the modal page title shows the value based on **previous** language (ENGLISH ) .

There's another issue about this :

if my report page and modal page use `&P0_TITLE.` as their title , when I open modal page it gets title of report page !!!

**Note : the value of page item is correct in session !**

what's wrong with it ? Is that a bug in Apex23.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug. I haven't worked with an application items for modal dialog titles but the important thing to bear in mind is that for modal pages, the title element belongs to the calling page.  So you have to make sure the item has a value in the rendered calling page (meaning: the value of the title must be set *when calling page is rendered*).

An item can be set in 2 ways: (1) in the pre-rendering phase (computation, page process, page item source, page item default, ...) or (2) by a dynamic action after the page is rendered. In this case, make sure the item is set in the pre-rendering phase.

--update

Looking at your application there are 2 issues that are preventing the modal dialog title to be shown.

1. The computation of the item containing the title has to be done *on the calling page*, NOT on the modal page. This was in my original answer but you must have missed this.
2. The case expression in the item computation does not have an else branch, so if none of the predicates yield true, a null value is returned.

Comment: How can I make sure about the value of page item has set before page rendered ? I really don't know what should I check on page

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: the process for the page item is on "ON LOAD : BEFORE HEADER " and the sequence is the first but still nothing has changed

Comment: I suggest you create a test case on apex.oracle.com, workspace SO_HELP, username/pwd SO_77527445/SO_77527445. I'm happy to take a look. Create a new application for this test case

Comment: I've create a FORM_TITLE_TEST_FAEZEH application . please check it out and besides thanks a million sir

Comment: Updated my answer